# Query Designer Settings

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, editor

I seem to have a setting that is not what I want in my query window and I can't figure out what it is called to change it in SQL management studio for 2008.

At the end of a JOIN statement (or other statements) where I alias a table, if I use D or E and then hit the return key, autocomplete changes the D to DELETE and E to EXECUTE.  In the past when I hit the return key, the cursor would make a new line, which is what I want.

Anyone know what settings correlate with this action?  I'd like to change them.

Comment: try to install sql prompt it is better for you

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue with D and E...it is part of the SSMS Tool Pack I recently installed.  In that tool pack it is part of the SQL Snippets section.  There are several one-letter snippets and I don't like the one-letter snippets so I just deleted them